# How to optimize a cycle?

Tags: c++, optimization, assembly, intrinsics, sse2

I have the following bottleneck function.

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
void CompareArrays(const byte * p1Start, const byte * p1End, const byte * p2, byte * p3)
{
     const byte b1 = 128-30;
     const byte b2 = 128+30;
     for (const byte * p1 = p1Start; p1 != p1End; ++p1, ++p2, ++p3) {
        *p3 = (*p1 < *p2 ) ? b1 : b2;
    }
}
```

I want to replace `C++` code with SSE2 intinsic functions. I have tried `_mm_cmpgt_epi8` but it used signed compare. I need unsigned compare.

Is there any trick (SSE, SSE2, SSSE3) to solve my problem?

**Note:**
I do not want to use multi-threading in this case.

Comment: Do you know which processor architecture you are targeting? Working with one 64 bit word chunk at a time (bit twiddling to make the comparisons in-register) could reduce memory bus contention somewhat. The compiler's assembly code should help provide ideas...
...and isn't SSE intended for floating point, not integer operations?

Comment: SSE has some integer instructions.

Comment: Why not made them signed? a simple XOR 0x80 with each element before comparation will do the job.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of offsetting your signed values to make them unsigned, a slightly more efficient way would be to do the following:

- use `_mm_min_epu8` to get the unsigned min of p1, p2
- compare this min for equality with p2 using `_mm_cmpeq_epi8`
- the resulting mask will now be 0x00 for elements where p1 < p2 and 0xff for elements where p1 >= p2
- you can now use this mask with `_mm_or_si128` and `_mm_andc_si128` to select the appropriate b1/b2 values

Note that this is 4 instructions in total, compared with 5 using the offset + signed comparison approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can subtract 127 from your numbers, and then use _mm_cmpgt_epi8

Comment: It seems like right answer. But I think that your 127 must be replaced with 128. Or xor with 128.

Comment: The problem is I think there's only a packed add in MMX, which is a different register set entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done in SIMD, but it will take a few steps to make the mask.

Ruslik got it right, I think. You want to xor each component with 0x80 to flip the sense of the signed and unsigned comparison. _mm_xor_si128 (`PXOR`) gets you that -- you'll need to create the mask as a static char array somewhere before loading it into a SIMD register. Then _mm_cmpgt_epi8 gets you a mask and you can use a bitwise AND (eg `_mm_and_si128`) to perform a masked-move.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, SSE will not work here.
You can improve this code performance on multi-core computer by using OpenMP:

```
void CompareArrays(const byte * p1Start, const byte * p1End, const byte * p2, byte * p3)
{
     const byte b1 = 128-30;
     const byte b2 = 128+30;

     int n = p1End - p1Start;
     #pragma omp parallel for
     for (int i = 0; i < n; ++p1, ++i) 
     {
        p3[i] = (p1[i] < p2[i]) ? b1 : b2;
     }
}
```

Comment: @ VJo - yes, of course. On single core computer this code performs exactly like original code from the question.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, many of the answers above are incorrect.  Let's assume a 3-bit word:

unsigned:   4    5    6    7    0    1    2    3 == signed:    -4   -3   -2   -1    0    1    2    3 (bits:     100  101  110  111  000  001  010  011)

The method by Paul R is incorrect.  Suppose we want to know if 3 > 2.  min(3,2) == 2, which suggests yes, so the method works here.  Now suppose we want to know if if 7 > 2.  The value 7 is -1 in signed representation, so min(-1,2) == -1, which suggests wrongly that 7 is not greater than 2 unsigned.

The method by Andrey is also incorrect.  Suppose we want to know if 7 > 2, or a = 7, and b = 2.  The value 7 is -1 in signed representation, so the first term (a > b) fails, and the method suggests that 7 is not greater than 2.

However, the method by BJobnh, as corrected by Alexey, is correct.  Just subtract 2^(n-1) from the values, where n is the number of bits.  In this case, we would subtract 4 to obtain new corresponding values:

old signed: -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 => new signed: 0 1 2 3 -4 -3 -2 -1 == new unsigned 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7.

In other words, unsigned_greater_than(a,b) is equivalent to signed_greater_than(a - 2^(n-1), b - 2^(n-1)).

Comment: If you look closely at my answer you'll see I'm using an *unsigned* min operation.

Answer (score -3):

use pcmpeqb and be the Power with you.

Comment: `pcmpeqb` is a check for equal. I need less compare.

Comment: ah yes. then pcmpgtb. still use the Power. but wisely.

Comment: OP needs unsigned comparison.